# python do dictionary vertically instead of horizontally with reading csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

so after I open a csv file with the context:

```
name,email,age
TOM,tom@email.com,13
BOB,bob@email.com,14
ANN,ann@email.com,15
```

I want to have the output like this:

```
{'name':['TOM','BOB','ANN'], 'email':['tom@email.com','bob@email.com','ann@email.com'], 'age':['13','14','15']}
```

This is my code so far, how do I get to that output?

```
def read_table(file_name):
open('file.csv') as lines
dic = {}
i=0
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(',')
    if line in lines[0]:
        key == line[i]
    elif line in lines[1:]:
        value == line[i]
    i+=1
    dic[key]=value
    print(dic)
```

Can someone please tell me where did I do wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, in case you ever want to use Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org)

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.read_csv("<yourNamedFile.csv")
temp.to_dict("list")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file isn't massive you can read the whole thing into memory and use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to switch the rows and columns.

```
with open("data.csv") as f:
    rows = [row.strip().split(",") for row in f]
d = {x[0]:list(x[1:]) for x in zip(*rows)}

# {'age': ['13', '14', '15'],
#  'email': ['tom@email.com', 'bob@email.com', 'ann@email.com'],
#  'name': ['TOM', 'BOB', 'ANN']}
```

If you don't want to use `zip`:

```
d = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in [[row[i] for row in rows] for i,_ in enumerate(rows[0])]}
```

Comment: is there another way without using zip?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can reproduce the behaviour of `zip` here with a nested list comprehension, but you should use `zip`.

Comment: can you show me the alternate way to do it because I dont get how zip works

Comment: Edited with a link to the docs and code you can use instead of `zip`. You should learn how to use `zip` - it's very useful.

Comment: can I select the key and make it into dictionary?
like 'something' = the first index of first line(which is 'name')
then do 
dic['something']=line[0]?

Comment: Yes, you can do it lots of ways. In my opinion this is the cleanest.

Comment: how do you get the 'name', 'age', and 'email'? do you go for line in lines[0]? because when I do it that way, it returns bool

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I want to make the first line as the key (name,email,age), the other 3 lines as values. so I do dic[key]=value. after I print dic, I get the output I want. how do I select the first line as key?

Comment: You can retrieve the values by accessing they key you are interested in. `print d['age']` would print `['13', '14', '15']`

Comment: The dictionary comprehension makes the first line the key and the remaining lines the values - `x[0]:x[1:]`

Comment: just edited my new code, can you check where did I do wrong? because I don't really get '_ in enumerate(rows[0])' and how can you use 'x', sorry I am a new python user, have only a lack of knowledge to use it

Comment: can you help me with that ^

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code. Use one of the better approaches proposed here or in the other question you asked.